# add into multidimension array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create/fill two multidimension arrays within a loop.

$internal_array = array();
$external_array = array();

Within a loop, I am trying fill them randomnly, so for example if, for every iteration, my variable is "internal", I'll fill internal_array otherwise external_array.

This array has three cells as shown below.

I am not sure how would I insert into my array, as an example, this is what I am trying:-

```
$internal_array = array("mystring1", "mynumber1", "order1");


$external_array = array("mystring4", "mynumber4", "order4");
```

This seems to not work for somereason.

I am hoping that by the end of loop, I'd have a multidimensional array like:-

```
internal_array = [0] ("mystring1", "mynumber1", "order1")
                 [1] ("mystring2", "mynumber2", "order2")
                 [2] ("mystring3", "mynumber3", "order3")

external_array = [0] ("mystring4", "mynumber4", "order4")
                 [1] ("mystring5", "mynumber5", "order5")
                 [2] ("mystring6", "mynumber6", "order6")
```

Any idea please?

Thanks.

Comment: Where the `$category` comes from? Make sure that `$i < count` is valid statement, that way `count` will be interpret as constant ant not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop with every occurrence you are re-populating the same variable over and over again `$internal_array = [some_value]`, so it will contain the last values populated only, using `$internal_array[] = [some_value]` will add every item in the loop as a subsequent array member

```
for($i=0; $i<count; $i++){

         if ($category == "internal") {
            $internal_array[] = array("mystring1", "mynumber1", "order1");

         }
         elseif ($category == "external") {
            $external_array[] = array("mystring4", "mynumber4", "order4");
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add them all in one shot like this:

```
array_push(
    $internal_array,
    array("mystring1", "mynumber1", "order1"),
    array("mystring2", "mynumber2", "order2"),
    array("mystring3", "mynumber3", "order3")
);
```

See [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)